# How to make a conditional compilation flag available to QT moc files?

Tags: c++, qt, moc

I have test.cpp and test.h files.
inside these files I need to have a conditional compilation.

```
#ifdef CPR
    int iParameter=1;
#else
    int iParameter=2;
#endif
```

From the shell script when I invoke the compilation, based on the compilation flags I export something like CPR_BUILD.

```
export CPR_BUILD=y
```

In makefile of this folder

```
ifeq ($(CPR_BUILD),y)
    CXXFLAGS+=CPR
endif
```

This works for .cpp file.
But the conditional compilation does not work for **moc_test.h.cpp** file.

I guess I need to do something in module_name.pro file to make this available to moc. But not sure how. Tried something like below, but it din't work.

```
CPR_BUILD {
  DEFINES += CPR
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There already is a Preprocessor symbol for the moc run:

```
Q_MOC_RUN
```

See [moc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/moc.html).

So you could do something like this:

```
#ifdef Q_MOC_RUN
    #define CPR
#endif
```

Comment: this need to be added in module_name.pro file ??

Comment: How do I make use of CPR_BUILD to define CPR for moc?

Comment: No, this is for the cpp/h file. If you distinguish between moc'ing and compiling afterwards, you can use this symbol instead of `CPR` or to not rewrite everything write the ifdef and define `CPR` somewhere as I suggested (e.g. in a "defines.h" and include it where needed).

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. sorry for the long delay to update here.

.pro file can be used if build root or some other environment is used that supports .pro file. In my case, it was not used.

It was a simple makefile based compilation where Qt is used. Hence "moc" {Qt's meta object compiler} comes to picture.

As I specified in the question, **#ifdef CPR** never worked. This is while moc was processing the header files. This error was seen even if **"CFLAGS+=CPR"** was present in the makefile.

**The solution**
From Makefile, we do invoke moc and pass it header files with a little bit renaming. something like this: moc_.cpp
The mistake was while invoking moc, CFLAGS  was not passed to it. In fact passing complete CFLAGS to moc is illogical and unnecessary. Hence I hence I had to only pass -DCPR while invoking moc.